# Can't install a specific numpy version

Tags: python, numpy

My code isn't working with the current version of numpy I have `numpy 1.20.3`.

I've been trying to revert it to version `numpy 1.19.4`, but `conda` won't uninstall it.

If I try to uninstall it and try to install `conda install numpy=1.19.4` and use `print(numpy.__verison__)` I still get a return of 1.20.3. Not sure what is going on here and why but apparently to get my code to work I just need this simply fix...but this simple fix is literally not working.

Comment: Try and start with a completely new Conda environment from scratch, but using NumPy version 1.19.4.

Comment: I think this will be easiest. I'll try this. Am I correct in thinking this is the ```conda create --new_env```

Comment: Just tried this. It worked - but I also made sure to run ```--freeze-installed``` for some specific packages.